# Intersection of kernels of two matrices with nonlinear coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, nonlinear-system, implicit-function-theorem

Consider $A$ a $n\times n$ skew-symmetric matrix and $B$ a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, the coefficients of which are (independent) nonlinear equations in $t_1,\dots,t_n$. For example, the element $(1,1)$ of $A$ could be $a_{11}=\sin(3t_1)+\sqrt{2}\sin(t_2)$.

Is it true to say that, in general, there is no $(t_1,\dots,t_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $0\neq x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax=0$ and $Bx=0$?

I would think that this is false because necessarily, $A,B$ are singular, so both matrix equations give at most $2(n-1)$ scalar independent equations for $2n$ unknowns $(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ and $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, corresponding to an underdetermined system. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Why is B singular?

Comment: @Element118 Because $Bx=0$ and $x\neq 0$.

Comment: I see you are trying to go by a proof by contradiction. You might want to write that you are attempting a proof by contradiction in your question.

Comment: @Element118 I am just saying that $x\neq0$ and $Bx=0$ implies that $B$ is singular. I don't think proof by contradiction has something to do with it. And then, it follows that the system of nonlinear equations is underdetermined. Well, in fact I am not sure because $\det(B)=0$ and $\det(A)=0$ add two equations...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Isn't it easy to generate a counterexample by setting $A(0)=B(0)=0$? E.g. let $B(t_1,t_2)=\pmatrix{t_1&t_1^2\\ t_1^2&t_1^3}$ and $A=\pmatrix{0&-t_1^4\\ t_1^4&0}$. Then $\ker A(0,0)\cap\ker B(0,0)=\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @user1551 Well, if you _choose_ $A,B$, you can find examples with an infinity of solutions, or without any solutions. In the case I am facing, $A$ and $B$ are imposed, that's why I specified "in general": some particular values could not follow the general case. But it's not very clear to me :/ What I am trying to do is to count the (a priori) independent equations and compare it to the number of unknowns $2n$. I am not sure if it a good idea though...

Answer (score 1):

We work over $\mathbb{C}$ ( not over $\mathbb{R}$) and we assume that $A=[a_{i,j}],B=[b_{i,j}]$ where $a_{i,j},b_{i,j}$ are "generic" (to get an idea: random chosen polynomials) algebraic functions of $(t_1,\cdots,t_n)$.

You want that there is $x\not= 0$ s.t. $Ax=Bx=0$. Then necessarily $\det(B)=0$. Then $V=\{(t_i)|\det(B)=0\}$ is an algebraic set of dimension $n-1$. For a generic $(t_i)\in V$, there is a sole solution of $Bx=0$ in the form $x((t_i))=[1,a_2((t_i)),\cdots,a_n((t_i))]^T$ where $(t_i)\in V$ and the functions $a_2,\cdots,a_n$ are unique. It remains to consider the equality $Ax((t_i))=0$, that is $n$ equations in $(t_i)$.

Case 1. $n$ is odd. Then, for any $(t_i)\in V$, $\det(A)=0$ and there are only $n-1$ algebraically independent relations linking the elements of $V$. Generically, there are a finite number of solutions.

EDIT. My reasoning when $n$ is even was false and the anderstood's comment is correct. Moreover, I edited also the example when $n=3$.

According to Fitzgerald, too much of anything is bad, but too much Champagne is just right -except when doing maths-.

Case 2. $n$ is even. Then $x((t_i))\not=0$ and $x((t_i))^TAx((t_i))=0$, that is a non-trivial combination of our $n$ equations in $((t_i))$. Generically $n-1$ equations are enough (in particular, they imply that $\det(A)=0$). As when $n$ is odd, generically, there are a finite number of solutions (a countable number if the functions $(a_{i,j}),(b_{i,j})$ are holomorphic and not algebraic).

Example with $n=3$. Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-w&v\\w&0&-u\\-v&u&0\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\b&d&e\\c&e&f\end{pmatrix}$ and let $s=[df-e^2,-bf+ce,be-cd]^T,p=[a,b,c]^T,q=[u,v,w]^T$. Under the condition, $\det(B)=<p,s>=0$ the solution (unique up to a factor if $rank(B)=2$) is $s\not=0$, satisfying also $As=s\wedge q=0$.

1. $q\not=0$. Then $s$ and $q$ are parallel vectors ($2$ relations) whence a total of three relations linking $t_1,t_2,t_3$; finally we obtain generically a finite number of solutions.
2. $q=0$ ($3$ relations) whence a total of four relations; generically there are no solutions.

Comment: I think that the Case 2 is wrong: when $n$ is even, $Ax=0$ gives still $n-1$ independent relations. Indeed, $x\neq 0$ so $\exists i_0\mid x_{i_0}\neq 0$. But $A$ is skew-symmetric so $x^T Ax=0$, hence necessarily $x_{i_0}\sum_j A_{i_0,j}x_j = -\sum_{i\neq i_0,j} A_{i,j} x_j$. In other words, the nullity of $k-1$ lines of $Ax$ implies the nullity of the line $i_0$. Hence generically, there are $k-1$ independent equations.

Comment: For example with $n=2$: $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & u \\ -u & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}=0_2$ gives $ux_1=0$ and $-ux_1=0$, i.e. 1 equation.

Comment: @ anderstood , your argument does not work. Indeed $x^TAx=0$ is a formal equality and not an equation; then, from this equality, you can infer nothing. In your example when $n=2$, your calculation is false: we obtain $ux_2=0,-ux_1=0$ and one equality does not imply the other. In fact, $(x_1,x_2)\not= 0$ imply $u=0$. Finally, there is a non-trivial solution iff $u=0,\det(B)=0$, that is $2$ relations between $(t_1,t_2)$ and consequently, there are (possibly) a finite number of solutions. There is a bug in my solution for even $n$, at least when $n=2$. I'll study the question.

Comment: Oh, the first equation in my example is obviously wrong, sorry. However, if $(x_1,x_2)\neq (0,0)$; let's say wlog that $x_1\neq 0$. Then $-ux_1=0\Rightarrow u=0 \Rightarrow ux_2=0$. So there is only one equation to satisfy.

Comment: @ anderstood ; no, you don't know what is the index $i$ s.t. $x_i\not=0$. Only one equation implies the other and you don't know it !

Comment: Do you agree that generically, $x_1\neq 0$ and $x_2\neq 0$? Then, any index $i$ would suit.

Comment: I would say that the intersection of the kernels is governed by $n-1$ equations among the $n$ equations. Generically, any $n-1$ equations would suit, but in some cases their indices cannot be arbitrary. However, even in the non-generic case, the number of independent equations is $n-1$ (the difficultly is just that you don't know which ones) and so the set of solution should, as in the odd case, be a countable set of points.